# Getting error in my onBindViewHolder in my recyclerview adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to implement like google plus animation in my `RecyclerView`'s `CardView`. I get an error in my `onBindViewHolder` method.

The error cannot resolve symbol `lastPosition` and cannot resolve symbol `position` here my two errors.

This here my `onBindViewHolder` method code:

```
public class SimpleCardViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleCardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {





private List<CardViewData> mDataset;

public SimpleCardViewAdapter(List<CardViewData> dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.primary_layout, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final CardViewData cardViewData = mDataset.get(i);

    viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cardViewData.getTitle());
    viewHolder.mDescription.setText(cardViewData.getDescription());
    viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(cardViewData.getImage());

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (i > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = i;
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Title: " + cardViewData.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset == null ? 0 : mDataset.size();

}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTitle;
    public TextView mDescription;
    public ImageView mImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        mDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_description);
        mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_image);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Where are position and lastPosition declared?

Comment: Can you post logcat?

Comment: directly it showing error @pratik Butani

Comment: @vishnu Paste your full code for your adapter so I will be able to help you. When you do this, notify me replying on my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the constructor to pass `Context` to adapter. It will fix your problem with `context`. When you initialize adapter, call `getActivity()` as argument for `Context`.

I don't see any logic in `lastPosition`, what default variable should be, so only I can do is declare and initialize this variable.

```
private List<CardViewData> mDataset;
private int lastPosition = 0;
private Context context;

public SimpleCardViewAdapter(Context context, List<CardViewData> dataset) {
    mDataset = dataset;
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: after changing that i am getting another Error in my activity                                     error:Error:(56, 20) error: constructor SimpleCardViewAdapter in class SimpleCardViewAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,List<CardViewData>
found: List<CardViewData>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length@Damian Kozlak

Comment: I wrote in my answer that when you initialize your adapter with `new SimpleCardViewAdapter(dataset)`;, you need to change it to `new SimpleCardViewAdapter(getActivity(), dataset);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    final CardViewData cardViewData = mDataset.get(i);

    viewHolder.mTitle.setText(cardViewData.getTitle());
    viewHolder.mDescription.setText(cardViewData.getDescription());
    viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(cardViewData.getImage());
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (i > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);
    viewHolder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = i;

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Title: " + cardViewData.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: one error solved,and i am getting 2 more errors, can't resolve symbol context and lastpostion in this line Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            (i > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom
                    : R.anim.down_from_top);@oalpayli

Comment: initialize lastPosition and pass the activity context which you get in your adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full code , no wonder why it says cannot resolve the symbol 'lastPosition' .

Initialize the variable first at the starting of the class , like below

```
public class SimpleCardViewAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleCardViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

int lastPosition = 0 ; // Here is the initialization

private List<CardViewData> mDataset;
public SimpleCardViewAdapter(List<CardViewData> dataset) {

    // your code here 

}
}
```

I think you copy pasted the code from somewhere. If so provide the link from where you copied so that we can help you easily.

And your another error , **cannot resolve symbol 'position'** is not possible. Are you sure you are getting that error ?